# Copy to new variable in lambda

Tags: python, lambda

Is it possible to do something like the following in a python `lambda` function? If so, how could something like this be accomplished?

```
def modify(**kwargs):
    from copy import deepcopy
    new_kwargs = deepcopy(kwargs)
    new_kwargs['x'] = new_kwargs['x'] * 2
    return new_kwargs
```

Comment: Probably not cleanly. Why not just use the function that already works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Python 3.8's assignment expression, you can accomplish the equivalent semi-reasonably:

```
>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>> modify = lambda **kwargs: dict(new_kwargs := deepcopy(kwargs), x=new_kwargs['x']*2)
>>> modify(x=4)
{'x': 8}
```

However, this creates an additional shallow copy for no good reason. It is also not very readable.

Leaving aside the fact that it is against the style guidelines to assign a lambda to a name (because it defeats it singular purpose), I would just stick with your full function definition, because it is clearer and more efficient.

Answer (score -2):

You can just create a new `dict` and return that without having to name it. For example:

```
>>> modify = lambda **kwargs: dict(kwargs, **{'x':kwargs['x']*2})
>>> modify(x=4)
# {'x': 8}
```

Comment: That doesn't do the deep copy any more, though. I don't know why you were doing the deep copy, but if you needed it, well, now you don't have it.